# Silverlight Context Menu IsOpen Exception?

Tags: c#, silverlight, contextmenu, toolkit, hresult

I have a project with a Templated Silverlight Control. When I add the DLL from the Project (with Templated Control) in my MainPage and want to open the Context Menu with a right click, I get this error:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<MyControls:Draw x:Name="ctrDraw"></MyControls:Draw>
```

**Draw.cs** (Templated Silverlight Control)

```
_contextMenu.IsOpen = true; --> Error
```

**ErrorMessage**

```
errMsg  "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: Das Festlegen von Eigenschaft 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' hat eine Ausnahme ausgelöst."
```

Comment: Can you give some more source code? I'm trying to determine if you have _contextMenu defined correctly

Comment: see the code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Init:

```
 private ContextMenu _contextMenu;
 private MenuItem _contextMenuItem;
```

Event:

```
private void map_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, GraphicMouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
_contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

_contextMenuItem = new MenuItem();
_contextMenuItem.Header = "Edit";
_contextMenu.Items.Add(_contextMenuItem);
_contextMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(menuItem_Click);
```

.....

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly but you can find "ContextMenuService" class and try set like:

```
ContextMenuService.SetContextMenu(ctrDraw, _contextMenu)
```

Comment: The method IsOpen works if I create a ContextMenu directly in the Main Page file. When I add a DLL(my own Control) to my project and this includes a context menu it crashes.